# Couldn't find anywhere - what does $F_{-X}$ mean in terms of distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Couldn't find anywhere - what does $F_{-X}$ mean in terms of distribution?

From definition: $F_X(t) = P(X \leq t)$, so what does $F_{-X}$ mean? is that $P( -X \leq t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, $F_{-X}(t) = P( -X \leq t)$